# Configuring Spring Boot to Support an XML-Based Liquibase Changelog File Instead of YAML

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have configured the following in my src/main/resources/application-local.yml file:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    drop-first: false
    change-log: classpath:/liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml
    default-schema: public
    user: postgres
    password: postgres
  #Connexion avec la base de données Postgres
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pg01lcommon
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      minimumIdle: 0
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      maximum-pool-size: 4
```

The change-log exists on my application :

[image]

I did the same things on test folder :

```
spring:
  liquibase: #https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html
    enabled: true
    drop-first: false
    change-log: classpath:/liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml
    default-schema: public #for Kafka connect source

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:pg01lcommon;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: sa
```

But when I run my application, I have 1 WARN :

```
02-11-2023 16:50:28.504 [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml does not exist
```

and this message :

```
Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'.
```

I can't understand why it doesn't want to take XML (it's like stuck at YAML). I have already tried to clean several times.

I am on the correct profile that I configured at start in my IDE: local

Comment: Where does the path '/db/changelog/  come from in the error message "changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'"?

Comment: I have nothing referring to this! I did a search throughout my project…

Comment: Are you sure your test `application.yaml` file is being picked up by the spring-boot `test` profile? Because `classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` is the default path and file name for liquibase, if `spring.liquibase.change-log` property is not set

Comment: The profile il not test but local. How do you know the good profile to use ?